# C# best way to simulate a device with screen and dim it

Tags: c#, screen

I've been messing around with this for a couple of months and I'm still not certain of what I can do to accomplish want a want.

I need to build a real device, that is, that exists in the real world and has a screen on it. So far, I have done it in a few different ways, like, using panels to simulate lays, etc. Now I'm currently building each control using code.

The thing is, is there any better way to draw this screen?
How can I dim it, make it darker or clearer?
I keep getting a transparent background behind the panels after I dispose them. Is there any way to remove this ghosting effect?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want a overlay that's on top of your form.

The open source project [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/overlays.html) implements a similar overlay. I hacked a little bit and it works.
You can download the solution at:
https://github.com/hamxiaoz/Misc/tree/master/DimScreen

Build the solution and drag the trackbar you can see the form is dimmed. And you can click through the overlay. I think that's what you want.

Comment: Isn't that my answer, just expanded upon??

Comment: Sure the concept is the same but I think the most important stuff is how to implement it (windows message/window creation parameters/pinvoke etc)

Answer (score 1):

The least invasive way would probably be a black or grey semi-transparent overlay. Just keep adjusting the transparency as needed until it looks the way you want it to.

I don't know if this works or not, but it should at least illustrate the technique:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

static class Utils {
    public static Form Plexiglass(Form tocover) {
        var frm = new Form();
        frm.BackColor = Color.DarkGray;
        frm.Opacity = 0.30;
        frm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        frm.ControlBox = false;
        frm.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        frm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        frm.AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.None;
        frm.Location = tocover.Location;
        frm.Size = tocover.Size;
        frm.Show(tocover);
        return frm;
    }
}
```

Comment: the other thing is... it has a touchscreen, so that would have to be click-through...

Comment: I'm sure there's a way to make that work, although I don't have the answer right at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

I've added something to make it more productive. Here is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

static class Utils
{
    static Form ChildForm;
    public static Form OpenMask(Form tocover)
    {
        Form frm = new Form();
        ChildForm = frm;
        tocover.SizeChanged += AdjustPosition;
        tocover.Move += AdjustPosition;

        //frm.Move += AdjustPosition;
        //frm.SizeChanged += AdjustPosition;
        frm.BackColor = Color.Black;
        frm.Opacity = 0.50;
        frm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        frm.ControlBox = false;
        frm.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        frm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        frm.AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.None;
        //frm.Location = tocover.Location;
        frm.Location = tocover.PointToScreen(System.Drawing.Point.Empty);
        frm.Size = tocover.ClientSize;
        frm.Show(tocover);
        return frm;
    }

    public static void CloseMask()
    {
        if (ChildForm != null)
        {
            ChildForm.Close();
            ChildForm.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private static void AdjustPosition(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form parent = sender as Form;
        if (ChildForm != null)
        {
            ChildForm.Location = parent.PointToScreen(System.Drawing.Point.Empty);
            ChildForm.ClientSize = parent.ClientSize;
        }
    }
}
```